# Javascript Uncaught ReferenceError

Tags: javascript

I have simple Javascript code for onClick event but I get

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: validate is not defined
```

HTML:

```
<head>
    <script src="js/confirmation.js"></script>
</head>
...
<button type="button" name="confirm" onclick="validate()">Validate</button>
```

JS:

```
function validate() {
   alert("hi");
}
```

Am I missing something ???

Comment: are you sure that the js file is being referenced correctly? The code is correct, but it doesn't know what `validate()` is so you need to check you are referencing the location of the javascript file correctly!

Comment: Maybe, your js definition just in wrong scope. Try `window.validate = function(){...}`

Comment: check for errors in console, I think path of js file is wrong.

Comment: @smile22121 check the network tab if the path for the js file is correct, it shouldn't say 404.

Comment: column name or table name may be wrong

Comment: yes that's true, thank you

Comment: I Posted my answer below .try to mark with green tick my answer if it solution for you because it useful for future user .@smile22121

Comment: The user changed the question completely, thus the closevote. Then I realized this, I reverted the edit and retracted my vote.

Answer (score 0):

Because you're actually defining function `validate` on a local scope. The solution is quite obvious. Just make it global.

#### Define this function on global scope

```
function validate() {
   alert("hi");
}
console.log(this); //it must be the `window` object
```

#### Assign this function to the global variable `window`.

Replace

```
function validate() {
   alert("hi");
}
```

with

```
window.validate = function() {
   alert("hi");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this it will work :**

use global variable `window` to call the function `validate`.

```
/**
*
* Validate the input.
*/
window.validate = function() {
  alert("hi");
}
```

**Jsfiddle :** https://jsfiddle.net/uf1d4aab/1/